# List all the query shapes in mongo database or collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I was going through the documentation on the official site, where I happened to find out the [term `query-shape`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-query-shape) while browsing details over the indexes section.

The details look interesting and quite possibly a list of these could help me with all possible queries that are being raised to a cluster while I am planning to onboard an existing deployed application.

But the question that I have now is that is there a way to do the above on the command line for a collection(or complete database)?

As a side note, I use both compass community and robo3t as tools built over CLI to access the datastore and as well comfortable to run the command on mongo shell directly too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some more time and effort, I could find [`PlanCache.listQueryShapes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/PlanCache.listQueryShapes/) which was a slight variation towards the more recent version of mongo which I was using.

Seemingly the **[`$planCacheStats`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/planCacheStats/#plancachestats)** introduced in 4.2 was something I was looking forward to. The following query helped me list all the query shapes over a collection as mentioned in the [list query shapes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/planCacheStats/#list-query-shapes) section.

```
db.user_collections.aggregate( [ { $planCacheStats: { } } , 
                                 { $project: {createdFromQuery: 1, queryHash: 1 } } ] )
```